# Using Couchbase with thousands of different schemas

Tags: couchbase

Consider a multi-tenant application in which tenants are free to model their own schemas. I.e.: backend-as-a-service.

With these requirements a 'table' per bucket is undoable. Instead, I'm thinking of simply having an attribute 'schema-id' define the id of the schema. Each 'schema-id' is a compound key based on tenantId + schemaid.

As far as retrieval goes only 'get by id' should be supported. In that sense I'm only using Couchbase as a k/v store instead of a documents store.

Any caveats to the above? Would the sheer number of entities per bucket be a problem? Any other things to think about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key pattern idea sounds great to me. You will have to make sure your cluster is sized correctly and stays sized correctly over time.

If you wanted to really control everything tightly, you could even front the whole thing with a simple REST API. Then you could control access tightly, control that key pattern, etc. Each user of the service would get an API key that would give them a session.

Answer (score 0):

Going with different buckets for different schemas will not scale,because i think there is a restriction of only 10 buckets in CB.
Since the is key is known by the client we can map the data from CB to a particular class since we know what type of schema it will be from the key.

Example if the key is PRODUCT_1234 or USER_12345,then we know for first key the data is of type PRODUCT for 2nd it is of type USER.